# Springbatch FlatfileItemReader problem with & in line

Tags: spring-batch

I created an application using Springbatch. The batch read a csv file and do some stuff after. Everything works fine except when a line in the file contains the character &.

For example:

"BB1222";"Myexample & blabla";"tayoo"

I don't understand why and how to fix it, but the batch fail and can not convert the line in my object. It throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: start ....

I defined my reader like this:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Bank> bankReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Bank> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Bank>();
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setStrict(false);
    reader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Bank>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[]{
                            ...
                    });

                    setDelimiter(";");
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Bank>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Bank.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return reader;
}
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Your issue does not seem to be related to the presence of `&`. Here is a passing test with your example:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;

class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void testFlatFileItemReaderWithAmpersandInInput() throws Exception {
        // given
        String line = "\"BB1222\";\"Myexample & blabla\";\"tayoo\"";
        Charset encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        FlatFileItemReader<Bank> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setStrict(false);
        reader.setEncoding(encoding.name());
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Bank>() {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setNames("code", "name", "address");
                        setDelimiter(";");
                    }
                });
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Bank>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Bank.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        reader.setResource(new ByteArrayResource(line.getBytes(encoding)));

        // when
        reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        Bank item1 = reader.read();
        Bank item2 = reader.read();
        reader.close();
        
        // then
        Assertions.assertNotNull(item1);
        Assertions.assertEquals("BB1222", item1.getCode());
        Assertions.assertEquals("Myexample & blabla", item1.getName());
        Assertions.assertEquals("tayoo", item1.getAddress());
        Assertions.assertNull(item2);
    }
    
    public static class Bank {
        String code;
        String name;
        String address;

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't share the full stacktrace, but you probably have a line with less or more tokens than expected. Moreover, since you configured the reader with `UTF-8`, you need to make sure the input file is encoded in `UTF-8`.